# wait for dbpouch and lunar to finish their job

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, pouchdb

Here is my code in vanilla javascript :

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.2.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lunr/lunr.js"></script>
<script>
    var dbp = new PouchDB('my_database');
    var doc = {
        "_id": "mittens",
        "name": "Mittens",
        "occupation": "kitten",
        "age": 3,
        "hobbies": [
            "playing with balls of yarn",
            "chasing laser pointers",
            "lookin' hella cute"
        ]
    };
    //db.put(doc);
    dbp.put(doc);
    var loaded = false;
    var searchIndex;
    dbp.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then((response) => {
        searchIndex = lunr(function () {
            this.ref("_id");
            this.field("name", {boost: 10});


            for (row in response.rows) {
                temp = {
                    "name": response.rows[row].doc["name"],
                    "_id": response.rows[row].doc["_id"]
                };
                this.add(temp);
            }
        });
        console.log("finished");
        loaded = true;
    });

    setTimeout(function () {  //Beginning of code that should run AFTER the timeout
        console.log("done");
        result = searchIndex.search("mittens");
        console.log(result[0]["ref"]);
        //lots more code
    }, 10000);
    console.log(searchIndex.search("mittens"));


</script>
```

If i wait 10 seconds the search works. I've try to add await before the dbpouch search but it does not work.

How can i make my vanilla script wait for the indexing of my dbpouch database ?

because i have a :

```
(index):59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
```

Because my search is not ready. I would like to find a way to make my script wait for the search index to be finished.

when i try an await db.put(doc);

I have a

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async
> generators

here is a jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/bussiere/4p1q3L9j/1/

My main goal is to load the dbpouch in lunar then being able to make a search multiple time.

So doing the loding in lunr just one time, not each time i want to make a search.

regards

Answer (score 1):

You have a big problem in your code

```
dbp.put(doc);
```

pouchDB's `put` is asynchronous so the code is not in sync with the database.

Instead,

```
await dbp.put(doc);
```

or if you prefer a Promise based approach,

```
dbp.put(doc).then((response) => {
   // etc
});
```

The snippet below is based on your code, using async/await.

To a finer point, the `allDocs` index is ready after a `put` or `bulkDocs`; however for *secondary indexes* (map/reduce, mango) this is **not** true.  To ensure complete results for a secondary index, e.g. after a large bulk insert affecting a map/reduce view, the following code will wait for the secondary index to build completely.

```
await db.query(view_index, { reduce: true });
```

To see that technique in action consider [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999498/pouch-db-fast-search/64470203#64470203).

```js
// Use memory adapter for testing to avoid having to deal with an existing database
const db = new PouchDB('my_database', {
  adapter: 'memory'
});
// test doc
const doc = {
  "_id": "mittens",
  "name": "Mittens",
  "occupation": "kitten",
  "age": 3,
  "hobbies": [
    "playing with balls of yarn",
    "chasing laser pointers",
    "lookin' hella cute"
  ]
};
// convenience
const gel = id => document.getElementById(id);

(async() => {
  let header,result;
  // ops
  try {  
    // PUT is async.
    await db.put(doc);
    // allDocs index is ready. Not true for secondary indexes (map/reduce).  
    const response = await db.allDocs({
      include_docs: true
    });
    // setup lunr
    const searchIndex = lunr(function() {
      this.ref("_id");
      this.field("name", {
        boost: 10
      });
      for (row in response.rows) {
        temp = {
          "name": response.rows[row].doc["name"],
          "_id": response.rows[row].doc["_id"]
        };
        this.add(temp);
      }
    });
    // ok, search.   
    result = searchIndex.search("mittens");    
    header = "Search result";
  } catch (err) {
    // conflate error object and search result object.
    result = [err];   
     header = "Error";
  }
  // display result
  gel('header').innerText = header;
  gel('result').innerText = JSON.stringify(result[0], undefined, 3);
})();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.2.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.2.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lunr/lunr.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='header'></div>
  <pre id='result'></pre>
</body>
```

**Update**  Here's a Promise based snippet.  Once the db and lunr are initialized, a search button appears.

```js
// Use memory adapter for testing to avoid having to deal with an existing database
const db = new PouchDB('my_database', {
  adapter: 'memory'
});
// lunr 
var searchIndex;
var loaded = false; // true once index is ready.

// test doc
const doc = {
  "_id": "mittens",
  "name": "Mittens",
  "occupation": "kitten",
  "age": 3,
  "hobbies": [
    "playing with balls of yarn",
    "chasing laser pointers",
    "lookin' hella cute"
  ]
};
// convenience
const gel = id => document.getElementById(id);

(() => {
  // ops
  return db.put(doc).then(function(response) {
    // allDocs index is ready. Not true for secondary indexes (map/reduce).  
    return db.allDocs({
      include_docs: true
    });
    // setup lunr
  }).then(function(response) {
    searchIndex = lunr(function() {
      this.ref("_id");
      this.field("name", {
        boost: 10
      });
      for (row in response.rows) {
        temp = {
          "name": response.rows[row].doc["name"],
          "_id": response.rows[row].doc["_id"]
        };
        this.add(temp);
      }
    });

    loaded = true;

  }).catch(function(err) {
  // display init error.
    gel('header').innerText = 'Error';
    gel('result').innerText = JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 3);
  }).finally(function() {
    // display search button on successful init.
    if (loaded) {
      // enable search button
      gel('search').addEventListener('click', function() {
        search();
      });
      gel('search').classList.remove('hide');
    }
  });
})();

// search function
function search() {
  let header, result;
  try {
    result = searchIndex.search("mittens");
    header = "Search result";
  } catch (err) {
    // conflate error object and search result object.
    result = [err];
    header = "Error";
  }
  gel('header').innerText = header;
  gel('result').innerText = JSON.stringify(result[0], undefined, 3);
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.2.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.2.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lunr/lunr.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id='search' class='hide' style='margin-bottom: 1em'>
  Search for 'mittens'
  </button>
  <div id='header'></div>
  <pre id='result'></pre>
</body>
```

Comment: When i try an await db.put i have a Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async
> generators

Comment: Then Promises are your option